# Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+

Tags: java, android, android-studio

implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.+'
`error:
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.`

Comment: It could not find because there is not any. you have to switch to androidx and new material library

Answer (score 0):

**Go for this support:**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Since, 29.+ is not available currently.

Also, it is best that you migrate to AndoridX support libraries and structure.